# Construction of BST

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/group-multiple-occurrence-of-array-elements-ordered-by-first-occurrence/

Please check this question.

How to do BST method of this problem.

They have mentioned that total time complexity will be O(NLogN).

How is time complexity of tree is LogN for traversal?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

*search*, *delete* and *insert* running time all depend on the height of tree, or `O(h)` for BST. A degenerate tree almost looks like a linked list can produce a running time of `O(N)`.

On the other hand, consider a self-balancing tree such as AVL tree, the running time for lookup is lower bounded by `O(logN)` because like Binary Search, we divide the search space by half each time as in left and right subtree have almost identical height.